# Useing timers in Python to return different parts of a Json

Tags: python, json, timer

So, I originally tried this a different way, and then thought this might work better. However I ended up with the same issue. I am trying to create a text game in Python and I have a class called room:

```
class Room():
def __init__(self, id=0, name="A Room", description="An empty room.", description2="A dark and empty room.", neighbors={}):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.neighbors = neighbors
    if tick == 1:   
            self.description = description
        elif tick == 2:
            self.description = description2
    else:
        None
```

This class is pulling information from a Json file which looks like:

```
{
"name": "Courtyard",
"description": "You are standing in a large open air courtyard.",
"description2": "It is too dark to see.",
"neighbors": {"w":2}
```

}

I also have a timer set up in a test file which looks like:

```
import time
import sys

counter = 0

def tick(count):
    time_start = time.time()
    seconds = 0
    counter = 0

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds = int(time.time() - time_start) - counter * 5
        if seconds >= 5:
            counter += 1
            seconds = 0
    return count
```

Lastly I called the timer at the bottom of my main game file like so:

```
start()
main(player)
tick(counter)
```

What I'm hoping for is that the description part of my Room class to change to either description or description2 depending on the count stored in my timer, but it does not seem like my timer is working correctly or at least my Room class isn't exchanging the description. Currently I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 80, in <module>
    main(player)
  File "game.py", line 77, in main
    runCMD(input[0], input[1], player)
  File "game.py", line 64, in runCMD
    commands[cmd](player, args)
  File "/home/illyduss/Urth/Commands/commands.py", line 20, in look
    print (player.loc.description)
AttributeError: Room instance has no attribute 'description'
```

I also tried doing something like this in my Room class:

```
class Room():
def __init__(self, id=0, name="A Room", description="An empty room.", description2="A dark and empty room.", neighbors={}):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.neighbors = neighbors
    if tick >= 2:   
            self.description = description
        else:
            self.description = description2
```

Which only gave me description and never provided description2, and vice versa if I changed it to:

```
if tick <= 2:
            self.description = description
        else:
            self.description = description2
```

I think my AttributeError is because the counter is starting at something higher than 2 and so my if statement is never at 1 or 2 and returns None, which isn't a description then it throws the AttributeError. Which makes no sense to me, because my counter starts at 0, but what do I know I'm a n00b. So, is that theory correct and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`tick` is a *function*. Your `if`-statements

```
if tick == 1:   
    self.description = description
elif tick == 2:
    self.description = description2
```

never trigger.

---

Change `tick` to `counter`:

```
if counter == 1:   
    self.description = description
elif counter == 2:
    self.description = description2
```

and fix your `tick` function:

```
def tick(count):
    global counter # use the global counter variable, not a local one.
    ...
```

This still won't work though, because `tick` constantly increases the value of `counter`. Once its value passes `2`, your `if`-statements will fail again. I can't help you fix that because I don't get the point of having a counter in the first place.

Comment: I included the else statement that m170897017 gave me to check and make sure it ran and it always printed that else of "Sorry, counter is not at 1 or 2!". So just to make sure, I changed my first if to if counter == 0: blah blah and it appears that the counter stays at 0 and never advances. I now think my problem may be in how I am storing my count since it stays at zero.

Comment: Sorry it took a very long time to explain further, but the point in having a counter was to create a timer that would change the description that would print from description to description2. Later I am going to add a description3 and so on for various times of day. Lastly I was going to add a reset, as in counter = counter == 0 after it looped through the various descriptions. This should give me the element of time in this game. The reason why it took a while is because I now have tick() threaded along with my main() so I can use the cmd line. But the counter just sits at 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to return `counter` but not `count` in `tick` function. And it seems you don't use `count` variable which passed into `tick` function. Delete it.
Like this:

```
import time
import sys

counter = 0
# delete variable count
def tick():
    time_start = time.time()
    seconds = 0
    counter = 0

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds = int(time.time() - time_start) - counter * 5
        if seconds >= 5:
            counter += 1
            seconds = 0
    return counter
```

Second, `tick` is a function but not an `int` object so it will never equal `1` which means `self.description` in `Room` class will never be reached. Change `Room` class to this:

```
class Room():
    def __init__(self, id=0, name="A Room", description="An empty room.", description2="A dark and empty room.", neighbors={}):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        # use return value of tick function to compare
        if tick() == 1:   
            self.description = description
        elif tick() == 2:
            self.description = description2
        else:
            self.description = "Sorry, counter is not 1 or 2!!"
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This one created a different bug that I previously had. After I start the game in my Terminal it no longer prints my prompt or takes commands. To maybe give you a better idea of what I'm talking about, it still starts the program, but then once I get to the point where tick() would activate, during my getRoom phase, it is just a blank line instead of showing my command prompt of >>.